# Create DNS in lightsail entry using aws cli

Tags: dns, aws-cli, amazon-lightsail

Does anyone have an example of how to create a dns entry, for a lightsail hosted domain, using the aws cli?

I haven't been able to find an example of the format for the --domain-entry parameter of the create-domain-entry sub-command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command below will create an A record using the CLI

`aws lightsail create-domain-entry \
--domain-name mikegcoleman.com  \
--region us-east-1 --domain-entry \
name=blog.mikegcoleman.com,target=52.40.235.176,isAlias=false,type=A`

Note that you need to specify the region as all domain actions with the Lightsail CLI need to be performed against us-east-1

For a TXT record the following should work. I think there is some funkiness with the CLI that it doesn't like the inline domain entry, and needs the JSON to do the TXT record, so it's formatted difrerently from above:

```
aws lightsail --region us-east-1 \
create-domain-entry \
--domain-name 'mikegcoleman.com' \
--domain-entry '{"name":"test.mikegcoleman.com","target":"\"response\"","isAlias":false,"type":"TXT"}'
```

Comment: Thanks ... that's getting me closer, but when I try to add a txt record, I get an error indicating the target value should be enclosed in quotes:

aws lightsail create-domain-entry --domain-name example.com  --region us-east-1 --domain-entry name=example.net,target='"test123"',isAlias=false,type=TXT

An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the CreateDomainEntry operation: Input error: Target should be enclosed in quotation marks: test123.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I did try escaping the quotes with backslash, but got the same error.

Comment: @DavidG There is something weird about TXT records, the only way I can get them to work is using the JSON object and escaping all the quotes. I posted an edit to my answer above.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

I made use of Mike's syntax to create a TXT record for DMARC. (Thank you Mike!)

I'd been trying to create it in the UI.  I kept getting this error: `Input error: Target should be enclosed in quotation marks: ""v=DMARC1; p=none; rua="mailto:dmarc@YOURDOMAINNAME.com"".`

After trying several times with different recommended quote configurations, I bailed on the UI, and used Mike's syntax in a bash script. In my case, I also removed the extra quotes I had around the email address inside the `rua` portion.  This may have been the source of my errors in the UI.

Here's what successfully created the DMARC record for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

aws lightsail --region us-east-1 \
create-domain-entry \
--domain-name 'YOURDOMAINNAME.com' \
--domain-entry '{"name":"_dmarc.YOURDOMAINNAME.com","target":"\"v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:dmarcreports@YOURDOMAINNAME.com\"","isAlias":false,"type":"TXT"}'
```

Of course, replace `YOURDOMAINNAME` with your domain name, and the `mailto` name with the email at which you want to receive DMarc reports.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

The answer from @binarybelle to create a BASH script and add the command as the JSON version worked for me too in order to add a TXT entry for DKIM.

The extra trick with a long DKIM entry is to split the text key into 2 parts, so lots of escaping the extra double-quotes :-)

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/aws lightsail --region us-east-1 \
create-domain-entry --domain-name 'mydomain.co.uk' \
--domain-entry '{"name":"default._domainkey.mydomain.co.uk","target":"\"v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; \" \"p=MIIBIjxxxxxxxxxxxiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAurVgfLc8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9cRHBTEOIR4lmIgatpit\" \"t+v7oQzngmfKpBNoTeyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxQIDAQAB\"","isAlias":false,"type":"TXT"}'
```

Comment: It might be easier to create the entry by using jq to construct the json value.

Comment: Interesting idea. I've never worked with jq before (https://www.baeldung.com/linux/jq-command-json) so will look at that. In this case, I think it was escaping and then not escaping double-quotes which fooled most people! :-( Also, why would it also not work with the Lightsail web gui either. Afterthought... I never thought of escaping the double quotes in the web gui!